# Cannot send email to T-mobile address using Outlook

Tags: vba, excel, sms

I'm trying to send a text to my phone and my carrier is T-Mobile.

Here's my code:

```
Private WithEvents objReminders As Outlook.Reminders
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With olMail
    .To = "8011234567@tmomail.net"
    .Subject = "Email from " & item.SenderName
    .Send
End With

End Sub
```

In my sent folder it shows that the "email/text" was sent, but it never reaches my phone. If I open the email and reply all to send to the phone@tmomail.net I do get a text... Any help on why the VBA isn't actually sending the text?

Comment: This is placed in my Outlook Under Project1>Microsoft Outlook Objects>ThisOutlookSession and fires whenever I get an email.

Comment: Can you send email to *other* places (eg. gmail/yahoo) using the code provided? Or does the issue *only* exist when sending to `@tmomail.net` addresses?

Comment: Yes - this creates an outlook email object and I can add a .body and send to any email address.

Comment: Right .. but can other recipients (not at tmomail.net) get the messages that are created in this way?

Comment: Yes This will send an email to any address x@gmail.com, x@yahoo.com, etc. The problem appears to exist after the email fires as if T-Mobile can tell whether the email was generated programmatically vs manually submitted.

Comment: Can you trace the mail to see if it left your organization? I am assuming that it did. I feel like it might have been blocked somewhere else along the way. Since it was programmically sent i could see filters not liking that you don't have a body for instance

Comment: May be you should change the email body and make it plain text? `.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain`

Comment: The problem is that this code ran fine a month ago. It suddenly stopped working I never included a body to keep it short. I'm wondering if someone knows if there's any difference between manually sending and VBA and if there's some way to mask it if so...I'm pretty stumped. I even removed the code, saved, replaced the code, opened and closed the application - no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was on t-mobile's end. It suddenly began working without any change to the code or any notice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include a country code with the phone number for T-mobile.

http://www.wikihow.com/Email-to-a-Cell-Phone

> On T-Mobile I had to put a "1" before the 10 digit number.

Comment: I sent it with a "1" and without - not fixing it.

Comment: Is your phone an American number?

Comment: Yes - my phone number is a Utah number.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the right phone number? Also, have you tried to send an email by hand?

Comment: Yes - When I send it manually, it sends. It also worked programmatically a few months ago. When I step through my code it shows as sent in the sent folder of outlook, but it never reaches my phone programmatically. Manually it does... That's why I'm wondering if T-Mobile can detect the method of text generation if there's a setting or something that tips them off.

Comment: Have you tried putting something in .Body? It may be the empty email throws it off?